# Need to make selected text as bold/italic/underline using javascript, or need very basic text editors suggestions

Tags: javascript, textarea, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I am trying to figure out how to create a textarea with 3 buttons: bold, italic, underline. I cannot go with any WYSIWYG editor as I have tested most of them and no one fits my needs. (e.g. most are configurable and could give me the option to have the 3 buttons but problems come when I paste formatted text in the field. Even if I set everything up, with tinymce for example, I get problems.)

I really need a simple, basic, text editor with bold, italic, underline, and if I copy and paste formatted text in the textarea, I do not want it to act like a rich text editor, I want it to act like a real textarea, which will automatically remove ALL formatting. Peoples might say I could do it with properly-configured WYSIWYG editor but the answer is NO. I spent to many hours trying to configure the text editors to only accept bold, italic, underline and I got to many errors/bugs with all the well known WYSIWYG editors. I am not a programmer, I am a quality analyst so I'm used to find bugs.

Are there any suggestions on how to "create" a textarea with bold, italic, underline capabilities and that will only accept those functions? (not a rich text editor). With Javascript, I would like to avoid JQuery if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered or tried Aloha editor: http://aloha-editor.org/
It is simple, HTML5 compatible and doesn't use iFrames.  It does have problems in older versions of IE though.

Answer (score 2):

`TEXTAREA` does not support formatting or any HTML tagging. There are no javascript tricks to change this.

You're going to have to roll-your-own or configure an existing editor.